# R - Saving tibbles from a for-loop as new objects

Tags: r, for-loop

My function below works the way I want. I also want it to save the contents of `filtered_xfile`, which is a tibble, either to new objects, or to a list of objects (they are all different lengths so I'm not sure how that works).

I can't figure out how to save them with different names. For example fitlered_xfile1, filtered_xilfe2, filtered_xfile3. It prints them out just fine, but obviously overwrites when I save to an object and I just end up with the last xfile in the loop.

```r
items <- c('HG13_2', 'GLAI18_2', 'HG15_2')

zscore_misfit <- function(data, xfile, item, sid) {
  xfile <- xfile %>%
    filter((xfile$ZSCORE > z_high | xfile$ZSCORE < z_low) & 
             xfile$`ITEM LABEL` == item)
  
  filtered_xfile <<- xfile
  
  data <<- data %>% 
    mutate("{item}" := replace(.data[[item]], .data[[sid]] %in% xfile$`PERSON LABEL`, 7774))
}

multiple_zscore <- function(xxx) {
  for (i in 1:(length(xxx))) {
    data <- zscore_misfit(data, xfile, xxx[i], "sidtp")
    print(items[i])
    print(filtered_xfile)
  }
}

test <- multiple_zscore(items)
```

Comment: The function `multiple_zscore` takes only a single argument `xxx`.  where is `xfile` as input

Comment: Maybe you could use the `assign` base function. Note if you want to take the object from a function to the global environment you have to use `envir = .GlobalEnv`. More help: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/assign

Comment: `assign` worked! Adding it under `print(filtered_xfile)` as `assign(paste0(i, "_XFILE_", items[i]), filtered_xfile, 1)` created three new tibbles saved as objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as RobertoT mentioned in the comment using `assign` worked. Adding the line

```r
print(filtered_xfile) as assign(paste0(i, "_XFILE_", items[i]), filtered_xfile, 1)
```

below `print(filtered_xfile)` created three new tibbles with different names.

My function nesting and sloppy code probably isn't the best, but my questions is answered!

```r
items <- c('HG13_2', 'GLAI18_2', 'HG15_2')

zscore_misfit <- function(data, xfile, item, sid) {
  xfile <- xfile %>%
    filter((xfile$ZSCORE > z_high | xfile$ZSCORE < z_low) & 
             xfile$`ITEM LABEL` == item)
  
  filtered_xfile <<- xfile
  
  data <<- data %>% 
    mutate("{item}" := replace(.data[[item]], .data[[sid]] %in% xfile$`PERSON LABEL`, 7774))
}

multiple_zscore <- function(xxx) {
  for (i in 1:(length(xxx))) {
    data <- zscore_misfit(data, xfile, xxx[i], "sidtp")
    print(items[i])
    #print(filtered_xfile)
    assign(paste0(i, "_XFILE_", items[i]), filtered_xfile, 1)
  }
}

test <- multiple_zscore(items)
```